# How to simplify an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Seems like a pretty basic question, but how can I simplify an array such as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [blue_dog_1] => 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [red_dog_1] => 4
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [red_dog_2] => 6
        )
)
```

To be like:

```
Array
(
    [blue_dog_1] => 2
    [red_dog_1] => 4
    [red_dog_2] => 6
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this way to make it single dimension from multi dimension using `array_merge`

```
$singleD = array_reduce($multiD, 'array_merge', array());
```

OR

```
$singleD = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $multiD);
```

Comment: That first `array_reduce` option is excellent, much cleaner than using a loop. https://3v4l.org/pNjYj

Comment: @MatthewWoodard, glad it works for you, actually there are various way to make multidimensional array to single dimensional, but I like array_merge mostly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
foreach($array as $sub_val)
{
   foreach($sub_val as $key=>$val)
   {
      $new_array[$key] = $val;
   }
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you can simply use [array union operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php).

```
$oldData = array(
             0 => array('blue_dog_1'=>2),
             1 => array('red_dog_1'=>4),
             2 => array('red_dog_2'=>6) 
          );

 $newData = array();
 foreach ($oldData as $arrayData) {
     $newData += $arrayData;
 }

 print_r($newData);
```